# CSV excel file write

Tags: matlab

I have data in a CSV excel file in the format:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4
   23         45         67         56 
   34         456        54         58
   56         32         53         56
```

I want to add one more column, i.e. Column5, with only 1 or 0 values :

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4    Column5
   23         45         67         56         0
   34         456        54         58         0
   56         32         53         56         1
```

Is it possible to write?  How to do this task?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: M = randn(4,4);
      dlmwrite('test.csv',M,'delimiter',',');
      N = randn(4,4);
     dlmwrite('test.csv',N,'delimiter',',','-append');    this code I have used but its not printing at the end of each row and also do not have idea to print only 0 and 1 .  Can you help me with the code.  @Suever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
h = actxserver('Excel.Application');  % Open Activex Server
e = h.Workbooks.Open('test.csv');     % Open file
% Give full path if your path is not set like this: 'D:\Assignment\test.csv'

e.ActiveSheet.Range('E1:E3').Value = round(rand(3,1)); %Writing required data
e.Save           % Saving the changes
e.Close(false)   % Closing the file
h.Quit           % Quitting the Activex server
```

---

**Comparison:**

[image: test file]